# How can I access the ref of the BaseComponent or any level of the components?

Tags: reactjs, recompose

Original question: https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/issues/232

How can I access the ref of the BaseComponent or any level of the components?

Code:

```
class BaseComponent {
    doSth(){...}
}
const Component compose(...some)(BaseComponent);

class App {
    componentDidMount() {
        // undefined(doSth) is not a function
        this.refs.component.doSth();
    }
    render() {
        <Component ref="component" />
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [hoistStatic](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#hoiststatics).

```
class BaseComponent {
  doSth(){...}
}

const enhance = compose(...some)

const Component = hoistStatics(enhance)(BaseComponent)

class App {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.component.doSth()
  }
  render() {
    <Component ref="component" />
  }
}
```

You can find a real example [in the test](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/src/packages/recompose/__tests__/hoistStatics-test.js).